# Show that the "calculation rule" is wrong for the given scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that the "calculation rule" is wrong for the scalar product
>   $\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{u}\cdot\left\langle\vec{v},\vec{w}\right\rangle$

I have problem showing that because I actually get a true result : /

I did:

Let $\vec{u}= \begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix}$, let 
$\vec{v}= \begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2\\ 
v_3
\end{pmatrix}$, 
$\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\ 
w_2\\ 
w_3
\end{pmatrix}$

Then 
$$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{u}\cdot\left\langle\vec{v},\vec{w}\right\rangle \Leftrightarrow (u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3) \begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\ 
w_2\\ 
w_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix}(v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3) \Leftrightarrow$$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
u_1v_1w_1\\ 
u_2v_2w_2\\ 
u_3v_3w_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1v_1w_1\\ 
u_2v_2w_2\\ 
u_3v_3w_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't see why it must be wrong? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equivalence is false. We don’t have :

$$(u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3) \cdot w_1 = u_1v_1w_1$$

Because : $(u_1v_1+ u_2v_2+u_3v_3)$ is a scalar ( a $1 \times 1$ vector).

Now can you continue your proof ?

Comment: $$(u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3)\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\ 
w_2\\ 
w_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix}(v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3) \Leftrightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1v_1w_1+u_2v_2w_1+u_3v_3w_1\\ 
u_1v_1w_2+u_2v_2+w_2+u_3v_3w_2\\ 
u_1v_1w_3+u_2v_2w_3+u_3v_3w_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1v_1w_1+u_1v_2w_2+u_1v_3w_3\\ 
u_2v_1w_1+u_2v_2w_2+u_2v_3w_3\\ 
u_3v_1w_1+u_3v_2w_2+u_3v_3w_3
\end{pmatrix}$$ which is indeed not equal ? It was an exhausting calculation for me I hope I didn't make a mistake. But I got your hint, I think and that's important for me :)

Comment: There is a mistake (or maybe I should say a typo ?) in your first matrix at the second line. But from this apart this is correct !

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much harder than necessary. To disprove a rule, you need merely show one counterexample. Here is one:

$$\vec{u}= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\vec{v}= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}.$$